# how to resume download while using NSURLConnection?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am trying to implement resume functionality while using NSURLConnection.
I read URL Loading System Programming Guide provided by apple but they didn't have the info.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such functionality. But you can create your own resume function. You'll need to add byte-range header. To achieve that you need to know file size and downloaded part size. And of course server must accept byte-range requests, otherwise its useless. Here is a sample of adding range header:

```
[request setValue:@"12345-99999" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
```

12345 - downloaded part size + 1 byte
99999 - total file size

Comment: BTW Id recommend u to use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) instead of NSURLConnection.

Comment: ASIHttpRequest is no longer maintained FYI.